# Finding LogTable for Java

Tags: java, logging

```java
class Logtable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("\n Enter your start, stop and increment: ");

        double start, stop, increment;

        start = keyboard.nextDouble();
        stop = keyboard.nextDouble();
        increment = keyboard.nextDouble();

        for (double i = start; i <= stop; i = i + increment)
            System.out.println("\nThe logarithm of " + i + "is" + Math.log(i));
    }

}
```

I have my code above written like this, but I'm receiving an error that states `"Could not find or load main class LogTable"`. What does this mean? How can I fix it?

Comment: Well, you don't have a class named `LogTable`, you have a class named `Logtable`.

Comment: Oh... thanks so much!